# The history.popstate not working and is called for both front and back buttons in browser

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html5-history, web-frontend

I am trying to get the previous state whenever i press the back button. In inspect, i could see that the popstate function is called for the forward button also. It is not returning to previous state eventhough the popstate function gets executed.I could not understand as how to co-ordinate the events correctly, as i am new to frontend development.
    Thanks in advance!!!

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="aid.js">    </script> 
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div id="one" ng-hide="val_1">{{val_1}} ONE </div>
<div id="two" ng-show="val_2">{{val_2}} TWO </div>
<button id="but" ng-click=myfun()> pressme </button>
</body>
</html>
```

aid.js

```
//the js code
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.val_2 = false;
    $scope.val_1 = false;
    $scope.myfun = function () {
        $scope.val_1 = true;
        $scope.val_2 = true;
        history.pushState("","","new");
    }
    window.addEventListener('popstate',function()
    {
    $scope.val_2 = false;
    $scope.val_1 = false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate

popstate is called for both forward and back buttons.